# What is it called when a word repeated?

Tags: expressions

reduplication?

If you make the tuna salad I'll make the "salad-salad"

That car is mine but it isn't  "mine mine" it's my brother's

I like him but I don't "like-like" him

Comment: Yes, reduplication.

Comment: From Wikipedia: [***Reduplication in linguistics** is a morphological process in which the root or stem of a word (or part of it) **or even the whole word** is repeated exactly or with a slight change.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduplication) But this is domain-specific terminology.

Comment: From @FumbleFingers’s link these, specifically, are examples of ***Contrastive focus reduplication***

Comment: The best part of reduplication is reduplication reduplication.  Just keep adding likes to add more emphasis.  “But what if he doesn’t like, like-like me?!"  “You mean, what if he like… only like-likes you?”

Comment: Very idiomatic.  I use it quite a lot (UK).  If I don't say *"...the car isn't mine mine; it's my brother's"*, I might say instead *"...the car isn't really mine; it's my brother's"*.  Although it's a bit of a mouthful, the best label for this usage seems to be *contrastive focus reduplication* (see answer below).

Answer (score 1):

**Reduplication** works.  This type of reduplication can also be called **contrastive focus reduplication** or **lexical cloning** <sup>[1](https://stancarey.wordpress.com/2012/08/07/contrastive-reduplication-a-thing-or-a-thing-thing/)</sup> <sup>[2](https://www.dictionary.com/e/reduplication/)</sup> <sup>[3](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FB%3ANALA.0000015789.98638.f9)</sup>.

[image: lexical cloning example from Zits]

Reduplication more generally includes combinations like *willy nilly* and *clip clop* <sup>[4](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/reduplicatives-and-their-meanings/)</sup>.

Comment: +1 for 'contrastive focus reduplication'.  (btw your links are not very helpfully organised; try to make the word itself the link rather than the tiny superscript)